# $mainframe->close() Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

In Joomla 1.5 when I like to call AJAX, I add function in the controller like so

```
global $mainframe;
        $idContact = JRequest::getVar('idContact');
        $modelContact = $this->getModel('clientcontact');
        if($modelContact->delete($idContact))
            echo "1";
        else 
            echo "0";
$mainframe->close();
```

And the controler return 1 or 0 (I dont need to use the raw or anthing else just `tmpl=component` in the URL)

In the 2.5 I have an error wiht `$mainframe->close();`

I dont like to use the raw or modal layout

Comment: Which Joomla are you using, your Question title says 2.5 and you refer to 1.5 in the body?

Comment: I said that in the Joomla 1.5 I use that code and evrything is Ok, but I put that code in the 2.5 i got error with the close() funtion <b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function close() on a non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\joomla25\administrator\components\com_tktransit\controllers\client.php</b> on line <b>44</b><br />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`global $mainframe;`

Was deprecated in 1.6 and is not available in Joomla 2.5 you should read the [Adapting a Joomla 1.5 extension to Joomla 2.5](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aAdapting_a_Joomla_1.5_extension_to_Joomla_2.5) article on the [Joomla Doc's](http://docs.joomla.org/) website.

If you're doing it the lazy way, then you can simply replace:

```
global $mainframe;
```

With:

```
$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();
```

throughout your extension.

In addition the `$option` global is gone.

You may also want to bookmark the [Developers portal](http://docs.joomla.org/Developers) on Joomla Doc's.

Comment: I already see this,I'm asking, if there is another why to call ajax without using raw?

Comment: @Rad - Have a look at [com_ajax](https://github.com/Joomla-Ajax-Interface/component). I was a component developed to make ajax much easier with Joomla. Comes default with Joomla 3.2 and can be installed on Joomla 1.5 and 2.5